# Внешний сервер grpc с приватным ключом и Go

Tags: сервер, golang, юнит-тесты, grpc

Как подключиться к внешнему серверу grpc через go ?

Comment: а можете указать какой протобоф у этого сервиса? ну или ссылку на сервис?

Comment: Скажи пожалуйста , нужно просто залить документацию proto на гитхаб и подключить его как pb?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor мне этот протобаф куда добавить?Я могу локально в папку положить их, а потом в го подключить?

Comment: да, так и нужно.  неважно где он лежит. важно, чтобы из кода был доступ.  обычно генерят  и кладут рядом с проектом. а клиент можнет тянуть из другой репы как зависимость

Comment: @SeniorPomidor а как можно локальный proto подключить к main.go?
package name.name.auth.v1;
option go_package = "authv1";
такие свойства в proto файле

Comment: из прото файла генерируете go код. используете этот сгенерированный код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для начала укажем куда нужно подключиться, все проверки на ошибку я опустил.

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial("127.0.0.1:1234")
```

есть возможности конфигурировать gRPC клиент с помощью ServerOptions. напрмер, `grpc.Dial("127.0.0.1:1234", grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock())`

Но это не все. Нам нужно работчать через протобаф. для этого зарегистрируем наш протобаф   `pb "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld"`

```
c := pb.NewGreeterClient(conn)
```

теперь мы можем отправить серверу, который реализует этот протобаф, сообщение.

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
r, err := c.SayHello(ctx, &pb.HelloRequest{Name: name})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("could not greet: %v", err)
}
log.Printf("Greeting: %s", r.GetMessage())
```

методы SayHello, HelloRequest, GetMessage реализованы в самом протобафе.

подробнее про это можно почитать в [официальной документации](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/basics/). примеры кода [тут](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/examples/helloworld/greeter_client/main.go)